# A step-by-step dialog for Qt5

Tags: c++, qt, dialog

I'm wondering if Qt 5 has a built in "step-by-step" dialog box complete with "next", "back", etc for me to use. I don't exactly know what this kind of dialog is called - I wish I could be more specific.

If Qt 5 doesn't have a built in step-by-step dialog what can I use to emulate this behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't know about Qt, but sounds like you want a wizard. Maybe having a name will help you search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are called Wizards: here's an example that can be useful: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/dialogs-trivialwizard.html

Answer (score 1):

There has been such a class in Qt for a while.

[QWizard](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtwidgets/qwizard.html)